# GetFinalPathNameByHandle fails for device handles

Tags: windows, winapi

If I create a File handle using `CreateFile` for a path like "\\?\NUL" or "\\?\pipe\", the handle is mapped to a File object that's opened for the "\Device\Null" or "\Device\NamedPipe" kernel Device object. Since the [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function supports the `VOLUME_NAME_NT` property, which already returns strings like "\Device\HarddiskVolume1\", I thought I would be able to obtain a similar path for a device handle. However, the call always fails, either with `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`, or `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, depending on the access flags the file was opened with.

In fact, almost any call to similar functions fails -- like `GetFileInformationByHandle`, `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, and even calls to NT functions like `NtQueryInformationFile` -- returning `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. The only functions that don't fail are `GetFileType` (able to identify a pipe), `GetVolumeInformationByHandle` (able to identify the driver), and `NtQueryInformationFile` with `FileModeInformation`.

All these functions work when used on any standard file, but they are not supported for device file handles. How can I obtain path information from a device handle? Are there some `Nt` or `Io` functions that would work? Is there some other way to identify a device if the only thing I have is the handle?

Comment: `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` call internal `NtQueryInformationFile` which send `IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION` to driver, on which device file open. than result already depend from driver implementation. say *ntfs.sys* (and most another filse-system drivers) handle this requests. but *npfs.sys*  handle it very restrictive

Comment: You can get the device name via `NtQueryObject`, but some devices support a namespace (e.g. "\Device\ConDrv\Output"), and this won't give you the remaining part of the name (e.g. "\Output" in the latter case). Process Explorer gives you the full name because it uses a driver to get it from the `FILE_OBJECT`.

Comment: yes, `NtQueryObject` with `ObjectNameInformation` information class

Comment: @eryksun Do not change my text formatting style, please. :-( But thanks for the function, it works perfectly!

Comment: @IllidanS4, ok, then just revert the change. Normally function names and constants are formatted as *code*, not in italics, and paths and the like are not code and don't need any special treatment.

Comment: @eryksun I usually don't use code formatting for names, unless they contain special characters (I remember making a post in meta about this). But I suppose it's not something that would be standardized here.

Comment: https://github.com/processhacker2/processhacker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm) and [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) have pointed out, the driver which implements the object must be able to handle `IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION`, but if it doesn't, the name of the object can be obtained via *[NtQueryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*, passing *ObjectNameInformation* (1) to it, which will obtain the `OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION` structure with the object name.

Since I intended to call it with C#, here is the P/Invoke code for it:

```
static class Ntdll
{
    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    static extern int NtQueryObject(
        IntPtr Handle, int ObjectInformationClass,
        IntPtr ObjectInformation, int ObjectInformationLength,
        out int ReturnLength
    );
    
    public static int NtQueryObject(IntPtr Handle, int ObjectInformationClass, IntPtr ObjectInformation, int ObjectInformationLength)
    {
        int length;
        int status = NtQueryObject(Handle, ObjectInformationClass, ObjectInformation, ObjectInformationLength, out length);
        if(status != 0) throw new Win32Exception(RtlNtStatusToDosError(status));
        return length;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION
    {
        public ushort Length;
        public ushort MaximumLength;
        public string Buffer;
    }
    
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void NtQueryObject(IntPtr Handle, out OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION ObjectNameInformation)
    {
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
        try{
            Ntdll.NtQueryObject(Handle, 1, buffer, 1024);
            ObjectNameInformation = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Ntdll.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION>(buffer);
        }finally{
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

The path can be then constructed by prepending `"\\?\GlobalRoot"` to the *Buffer* member.